# Rotation not working correctly on round objects

Tags: animation

I am trying the make wheels turn on a car. I set a keyframe on the wheel for rot on frame 0. I then rotate the wheel around the axis on the frame of the car 90 degrees (lets just say the x axis) and then set another rot keyframe on frame 10. When I play the animation, it goes from the first to the second position. However, it rotates in other directions too. When i try to set keyframes for the y and z rotations to 0, then the wheel is turned the wrong way. I tried this on other axis's instead of the X and the same thing happens. I use v 2.79. Any ideas? Thank you for helping!

Comment: Make sure you have applied rotation/transforms to the meshes CTRL+a. If that does not help open the Graph view and check the different axis and values at your key frames. If all else fails upload the file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/